# In android using kotlin, To copy a file it is necessary to delete a destination file if it is already exists, can overwrite without deleting it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, copy-paste, file-copying

```
public fun File.copyTo(target: File, overwrite: Boolean = false, bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE): File {
if (!this.exists()) {
    throw NoSuchFileException(file = this, reason = "The source file doesn't exist.")
}

if (target.exists()) {
    if (!overwrite)
        throw FileAlreadyExistsException(file = this, other = target, reason = "The destination file already exists.")
    else if (!target.delete())//I am stuck here because some files are not deleted, so without deleting I want to overwrite  
        throw FileAlreadyExistsException(file = this, other = target, reason = "Tried to overwrite the destination, but failed to delete it.")
}

if (this.isDirectory) {
    if (!target.mkdirs())
        throw FileSystemException(file = this, other = target, reason = "Failed to create target directory.")
} else {
    target.parentFile?.mkdirs()

    this.inputStream().use { input ->
        target.outputStream().use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output, bufferSize)
        }
    }
}

return target
}
```

**This method copy from:**

```
@file:JvmName("FilesKt")

package kotlin.io
```

This method throw "Tried to overwrite the destination, but failed to delete it" How I can handle this?

Comment: So how did you do it?

Comment: val sourceFile1 = File(pPage.file_path)
                    if (sourceFile1.exists()) {
                        if (destinationFile1.exists())
                            destinationFile1.deleteFile()
                        else destinationFile1.createNewFile()

                        sourceFile1.copyTo(destinationFile1, true)
                    }

Comment: doesn't need to delete I found alternate solution

`sourcefolder.copyRecursively(folder,true)` use `copyRecursively` kotlin utils